# 'rm'(linux) in the exec is not recognised as internal or external command.

Tags: node.js

The child_process module of node.js is not able to recognize the linux's 'rm' command. Am using it like

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('rm ' + ImgDir + '/formatted-*', function(error, stdout, stderr){});
```

But this says:

**stderr : 'rm' is not recognized as internal or external command,
operable programe or batch file.**

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: Yep looks like you are running on Windows. This error is from Windows.

Comment: You might consider using `fs.unlink` (http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/fs.html#fs.unlink) as it multiplatform, and will behave same way on most OS.

Answer (score 0):

Check what user the command is trying to execute as. Then check if it is in that user's `$PATH` if not add it to that user's `$PATH`. To log in as another user:

```
sudo -u username /bin/bash
```

you will now have a console as that user. Now try using the command.

This is your reason. It is most probably based on your distribution - different distros have different "settings" for different programs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to execute a Linux command on a Windows system. If you want to perform filesystem operations in a way that will work across all supported operating systems, you should use the [fs module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) instead of starting a child process.

[from the docs:](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback)

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.unlink("/path/to/file", function(err){
    // do stuff after you've deleted your file
    // or just resolve a promise and go on with your day
})
```

If you want to toast the whole directory, [use fs.rmdir](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmdir_path_callback):

```
fs.rmdir("/path/to/directory", function(err){
    // do stuff after you've deleted your directory
})
```

Another thing to note is that `fs.unlink` does not allow wildcards or regular-expressions, so you will want to use [`fs.readfiles`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) to enumerate the files and then `unlink` the ones you want to remove.

Comment: As mentioned above i made the changes ant it looks like `fs.unlink(ImgDir + '/formatted-*', function(error , stdout, stderr) {

if (stderr) {
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
return
}
if (error !== null) {
console.log('exec error: ' + error);
return
}
})`


But it says Error: ENOENT , Unlink on the image dretcory which am trying to delete. But seems like the directory exists and path seems to be fine.. 
Any thing else which am mising here ?